# Repeat a MAUI animation based on clicks

Tags: c#, maui

I have a very basic `Animation` in a `MAUI` project. When a user clicks on a `border` I want to spin the border and display a different test (like a flashcard).

[image]

How you can see in the above screenshot is:

- with the first click, the text change and then the card rotate (I want the card rotate and then change the text)
- after the first click, if I click on the `border` only the text changes.

The XAML is the following

```
<Border x:Name="border" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="300">
    <Border.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
    </Border.GestureRecognizers>

    <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label x:Name="label1" Text="One side" 
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="5" 
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</Border>
```

The code is this one:

```
int side = 0;
private async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
{
    var animation = new Animation();
    animation.Add(0, 0.5, new Animation(v => border.RotateYTo(v, 1000), 0, 360));
    animation.Commit(this, "ChildAnimation", 16, 2000);

    if (side == 1)
    {
        side = 0;
        label1.Text = "One side";
    }
    else
    {
        side = 1;
        label1.Text = "The other side";
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- how can I wait the animation is finished before to change the text of the `Label`
- how can I restart the animation

The top should be that when the animation starts there is a text in the front of the card and another one on the back and in the animation I can see both. Maybe this is too much :)

Comment: Commit has a finished parameter that allows you to provide a completion handler

Comment: OK, but how can I restart the animation again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After code ran the first time, Y-rotation stayed at 360.

Set it back to zero before each animation:

```cs
border.RotationY = 0;
```